# Pygame window displays blank black screen

Tags: python, pygame

Here is my code, please keep in mind that I picked up python a couple of days ago so my code may be incorrectly made, ect. I am trying to make a window that will display some text (beta) and will display two small rectangles that I want to make into buttons.

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

size = width, height = 720, 480
speed = [2, 2]
black = (0,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
green = (0,255,0)
red = (255,0,0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
screen.fill((blue))

pygame.display.set_caption("BETA::00.0.1")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def game_intro():

  intro = True

  while intro:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
         print(event)
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             pygame.quit()
             quit()

    gameDisplay.fill(blue)
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("BETA", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, green,(150,450,100,50))
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red,(550,450,100,50))

    pygame.display.flip(screen)
    pygame.display.update(screen)
    clock.tick(15)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems:

1. Indentation error
2. Your `game_intro()` function is defined, but never called
3. You wrote `gameDisplay` instead of `screen` 4 times, also `display_width, display_height` instead of `width, height`
4. In `game_intro()`, code after your infinite loop is never called
5. `pygame.display.update(screen)` does not work, it should be `pygame.display.update()` to update the whole screen. `flip(screen)` also needs to be changed to `flip()`
6. The function `text_objects()` is not defined but I found the definition in the example you probably copied the code from :)

Corrected code:

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

size = width, height = 720, 480
speed = [2, 2]
black = (0,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
green = (0,255,0)
red = (255,0,0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("BETA::00.0.1")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def game_intro():

  screen.fill(blue)

  largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
  TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("BETA", largeText)
  TextRect.center = ((width/2),(height/2))
  screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

  pygame.draw.rect(screen, green,(150,450,100,50))
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, red,(550,450,100,50))

  pygame.display.flip()
  pygame.display.update()
  clock.tick(15)

  intro = True

  while intro:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
         print(event)
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             pygame.quit()
             quit()


game_intro()
```

Comment: Thanks :), I was using a tutorial and got kindof confused between all the code